# Bind to IReactiveCommand in view code behind

Tags: viewmodel, winrt-xaml, reactiveui

I have my ViewModel which has an ErrorCommand. I wish to subscribe to this in my view code behind so that any time it is called I can display an error message which is passed like so:

```
ErrorCommand.Exectute("Error occured")
```

In the view:

```
this.WhenAny(view => x.ViewModel.ErrorCommand, x => x.Value).Subscribe(error => DisplayError(error));
```

This code doesn't actually work but hopefully shows what I'm trying to acheive. How would I do this correctly?

I understand I could use the MessageBus, but I also have a similar scenario where the MessageBus wouldn't be appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a method specifically for this scenario:

```
this.WhenAnyObservable(x => x.ViewModel.ErrorCommand).Subscribe(x => /* ... */);
```

will do what you expect and will avoid the null refs

Answer (score 0):

```
this.WhenAny(view => x.ViewModel.ErrorCommand, x => x.Value).Subscribe(error => DisplayError(error));
```

Will only fire when you change the value of the ErrorCommand property.

What you want is this:

```
ViewModel.ErrorCommand.IsExecuting.Subscribe(x=> DisplayError(x));
```

Comment: I am putting this code in the View constructor and at that time ViewModel is null as the property hasn't been set yet. And as such I receive NullRef exception

Comment: Then make sure this code is called after the ViewModel is set.